# SQL - Incorrect Date Format (Day & Month reversed)

Tags: c#, sql, date

When i read the Date out of my database i get the date in this format: `15.03.2022`.

When I then try to save the date (without changeing it) to my SQL-Database i get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

However when i switch the day and month of the date like this: `03.15.2022` this works.

Im asking myself why i cant save the date in the same format i received from the Database?

Also when I receive the Date i have tried to Convert it to a datetime like this:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("de-CH"); 
while (dataReader.Read())
{       
    Ablaufdatum = dataReader.GetValue(4).ToString();
    tempDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Ablaufdatum, "dd-MM-yyyy", culture);
}
```

Which gives me following error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Am i missing something for my enviorment to know the date format is `dd-MM-yyyy` and NOT `MM-dd-yyyy`

Comment: The date format you get from DB is "dd.MM.yyyy", while you parse to DateTime with format "dd-MM-yyyy".

Comment: have you tried storing and reading it as datetime, and not as string, so you don't have to worry _at all_ about conversion?

Comment: Assuming that the type on the server is a datetime type, why are you converting it to a string?

Comment: I would strongly recommend against calling `ToString()` in your code in the first place. Assuming the value is really a DateTime, just cast: `tempDate = (DateTime) dataReader.GetValue(4);`

Comment: @YongShun: We don't know that 'the date format you get from DB is "dd.MM.yyyy"' - I think it's quite likely that it's stored as a date/time value rather than a string value, and what's *actually* converting it into that format is the `ToString()` call.

Comment: Which SQL database are you using?

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: The Problem is that when i save it i get an SQL-Error that the format is not correct thats because i have 'dd.MM.yyyy' and sql tries to save 'MM.dd.yyyy'. I need a Function to switch dd with MM

Comment: The column datatype is Date

Comment: If it's a SQL Date type you should be able to just convert to a DateTime using the SqlDataReader.GetDateTime() method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetDateTime_System_Int32_

Comment: IMO, Sometimes when *Date & Time format* of *Regional Settings* of OS at App. Server is different from *Regional Settings* of OS at DB. Server; this situation may happen!

Comment: `tempdate = (DateTime)dataReader[4];` do not use `ToString()` just cast it

Answer (score -1):

```
Convert.ToDateTime(tb_datum.Text).ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
```

This worked for me. I have to switch dd and MM but in the database it is displayed correctly.